# How do you call a function to an Linq List query that uses the exist function

Tags: c#

I have this method with a linq statement below. I'm not a fan of multiple if statement and I'm trying to find what is the best way to not have these if statement and have a private method.

My field values is being set as such:

```
var fieldValues = await GetFields // then it's being passed to my method.

public static AppraisalContactBorrower BuildCoBorrower(List<LoanFieldValue> fieldValues) {
var coborrower = new AppraisalContactBorrower();

if (fieldValues.Exists(f => f.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.COBORRNAME")) {
    coborrower.Name = fieldValues.First(v => v.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.COBORRNAME").Value;
}
if (fieldValues.Exists(f => f.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP")) {
    borrower.Zip = fieldValues.First(v => v.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP").Value;
}
 if (fieldValues.Exists(f => f.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP")) {
    borrower.Zip = fieldValues.First(v => v.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP").Value;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is instead of this:

```
coborrower.Name = fieldValues.First(v => v.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.COBORRNAME").Value;
```

Is having something similar to this.

```
if (fieldValues.Exists(f => f.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP")) {
coborrower.Name = SETVALUE("CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP")}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try using [Enumerable.ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary) to have the field values grouped by `FieldId`, then use [IDictionary.TryGetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.idictionary-2.trygetvalue) to get the existing values:

```
public static AppraisalContactBorrower BuildCoBorrower(List<LoanFieldValue> fieldValues) {
    var groupedFieldValues = fieldValues.ToDictionary(f => f.FieldId)
    var coborrower = new AppraisalContactBorrower();

    if (groupedFieldValues.TryGetValue("CX.OS.AO.COBORRNAME", out var name)) {
        coborrower.Name = name.Value;
    }
    if (groupedFieldValues.TryGetValue("CX.OS.AO.BORRCONTACTZIP", out var zip)) {
        borrower.Zip = zip.Value;
    }
}
```

Using Dictionary makes it faster to check the appropriate field existence as it is O(1) and with `TryGetValue` you combine two operations into one (existence check + obtaining the value).

Answer (score 0):

Your two last statements are almost identitical. The equivalent of :

```
if (groupedFieldValues.TryGetValue("CX.OS.AO.COBORRNAME", out var name)) {
   coborrower.Name = name.Value;
}
```

is:

```
coborrower.Name = fieldValues.FirstOrDefault(v => v.FieldId == "CX.OS.AO.COBORRNAME") 
                  ?? coborrower.Name;
```

In the original code, `coborrower.Name` is not updated if the field doesn't exist in the list.